# Chef attributes value reuse

Tags: chef-infra, chef-attributes

Versions :

- Server 12
- chef client 12.13.37

I have an attribute file with a lot of url references but all to the same server. I'd like to reference a base url to build up the full path. Then if the source server changes I just change the top attribute.

original

```
default['cookbook'][1.1]['zipurl']  = 'http://server/something/version/SERVER.zip'
```

planned

```
default['cookbook'][1.1]['packagesurl'] = 'http://server/'

default['cookbook'][1.1]['zipurl']  = '"#{default['cookbook'][version]['packagesurl']}"something/version/SERVER.zip'
```

It compiles and uploads ok but the chef run returns the following :

```
"#default{['cookbook'][version]['packagesurl']}something/version/server.zip" is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs.
```

probably some basic syntax wrong ...

I looked in the attributes of some of the supermarket public cookbooks and they call use the full paths so this might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes (`"`) for `#{}` interpolation to work in Ruby. Also check out [poise-derived](https://github.com/poise/poise-derived/) for another option that might fix a few footguns before you find them yourself.

Comment: Many thanks coderanger I'll check out the 'poise-derived' project looks interesting.